# Pattern problem in C programming language

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, redundancy

I have the following pattern to print in the C programming language.

```
BBBB
BAAB
BAAB
BBBB
```

I have tried the following code, but it's not working.

**My code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
                {
                    if ((i==1&&j>=i)||(i==4&&j<=i)){
                        printf("%c",65+1);
                    }
                        
                
                    else{
                        printf("%c",65);
                }        
            }
        printf("\n");            
        }        
    return 0;
}
```

However, the pattern I am getting is the following.

```
BBBB
AAAA
AAAA
BBBB
```

Comment: `if (i==1 || j==1 || i==4 || j==4) printf("B");`

Comment: Rather than `65`, it is generally considered easier to read `'A'`.  You can also write `'A' + 1`, so there is no loss of generality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is your special case will *only* fire on the first and fourth row. We can see this a little better if we space things out.

```
if( 
  (i==1 && j>=i) ||  // `i==1` only on the first row
  (i==4 && j<=i)     // `i==4` only on the fourth row
) {
  printf("%c",65+1);
}
```

Every other iteration will use your `else` block that just prints `A`.

```
else {
  printf("%c",65);
}
```

Note: `'A'` is much easier to read than `65`, and `'B'` much easier than `65+1`.

---

There's plenty of ways to do this. Here's one elegant way with a single loop.

We can observe that we want to print `BBBB` at the start and every third row. If we start iterating at 0 we can do this when `i` is divisible by 3. 0/3 has a remainder of 0. 3/3 has a remainder of 0. We use the [modulus operator](https://study.com/academy/lesson/modulus-in-math-definition-examples.html) `%` to get the remainder.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if( i % 3 == 0 ) {
    puts("BBBB");
  }
  else {
    puts("BAAB");
  }
}
```

This will continue to repeat the pattern if you extend the loop. 6/3 has a remainder of 0. 9/3 has a remainder of 0. And so on.

(You could also start with `i=1` and check `i%3 == 1`, but get used to starting counting at 0; it makes a lot of things easier.)